# Stop animation of Recyclerview when load more data

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

i'm tying to load more data each time user reached at the bottom of `Recyclerview` by get data of next page , using this :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && isEnd) {
                page++;
                isEnd = false;
                new fetchData().execute(page);
            }
        }
    });
```

And everything works fine , but i have a problem with animation , each time i load more data `Recyclerview` disappears and shows.

here's my rest of code :

```
   public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Integer, List<Wallpaper>, List<Wallpaper>> {
        Document doc = null;
        ArrayList<Wallpaper> urls = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Wallpaper> doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(URLSource+"/page/" + integers[0]).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select(".thumbnail");
            for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
                String thumb = headline.select("img").attr("src");
                String title = headline.select("img").attr("alt");
                Wallpaper wallpaperInfo = new Wallpaper();
                URL = URL.replace("/wallpapers/", "/walls/");
                wallpaperInfo.setThumbnails(URL);
                wallpaperInfo.setTitle(title);
                urls.add(wallpaperInfo);
            }
            return urls;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Wallpaper> wallpapers) {
            super.onPostExecute(wallpapers);
            setAdapterForRecyclerView(wallpapers);
            isEnd = true;
        }

    }

private void setAdapterForRecyclerView(List<Wallpaper> wallpapers) {

        if (myAdapter == null) {
            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(wallpapers, getActivity(), new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, Wallpaper wallpaper) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullScreen.class);
                    intent.putExtra("img", wallpaper.getThumbnails());
                    if (wallpaper.getTitle().isEmpty()) {
                        intent.putExtra("title", "Unknown");
                    } else {
                        intent.putExtra("title", wallpaper.getTitle());
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                    /* TODO: FULLSCREEN ACTIVITY HERE*/
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, Category categories) {

                }
            });
            recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        } else {
            myAdapter.getItems().addAll(wallpapers);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && isEnd) {
                    page++;
                    isEnd = false;
                    new fetchData().execute(page);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

hope you guys help me to stop this animation , i just want to load more data without any animation

Answer (score 1):

i think that your problem is in the calling of setAdapterForRecyclerView as there you may create new adapter instance and set this new adapter to the recyclerview again which lead to this behavior.
i recommend to append the new list of wallpapers objects to the recyclerview list then call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: ,thank you for your answer can you please tell me how  i can append the new list

Comment: you can use addAll method this will add a list to new list:-
oldList.addAll(newlist)

Comment: your code seems should work but if you still have this behavior you can disable the recyclerview animation by recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

Comment: plus you don't need to set recyclerView.addOnScrollListener every time you changed the dataset

Comment: i have replaced `addOnScrollListener`  , also added `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);` , but i still have the same issue